# How can I combine 3 box plot in one graph in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, seaborn

I have 3 separated box plots build by code below, only the title is other, and my question is how can I combine these 3 box plots in one graph?
I would like to have on one graph 3box plots next to each other.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df1['rows'], name='rows', 
                         marker = dict(color = "brown", 
                                       line=dict(color="black", width=1),),opacity=1))

fig.update_layout(
    title="Wykres pudełkowy dotyczący podstawowych statystyk ilościowych kolumny rows w zbiorze 1",
    #xaxis_title="rows",
    yaxis_title="ilość",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=11,
        color="#7f7f7f"))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Could you provide some data and/or your current result and/or the desired plot?

Comment: source data are realy simply it is one column in data rame like this:

Comment: @pablo1212 Time spent on *recreating* your example means less time spent *answering* your question. To increase your chances of receiving a useful answer, please consider providing a runnable code snippet with a proper data sample.